# youtube data api v3(node js) keeps crashing

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios

I was working on a react app and I'm using the youtube data api v3 to extract the videoID from it.

Everything was working fine until it didn't.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require("axios");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const apiKey = "AIzaSyA5xVysG-ze6XOAOnfUCBzhlqRkOO3T550";
const youtube = google.youtube({
  version: "v3",
  auth: apiKey,
});

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await youtube.search.list({
      part: "snippet",
      q: "cat",
      type: "video",
      videoDuration: "short",
      maxResults: "50",
    });
    const videoid = response.data.items.map((item) => item.id.videoId);
    res.send(videoid);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is the code that i run on my server I go to localhost:3000/videosid to get my data.

but the problem is now that everytime I try access it crashes, and I don't really know why I even used github to go back to a previous working version but it still dies on me and I don't know what else to do.

Here's the messsage error :

```
C:\Users\The_rat\Desktop\randvid\randvidAPI\routes\videosid.js:23
    next(err);
    ^

    ReferenceError: next is not defined
    
            at C:\Users\The_rat\Desktop\randvid\randvidAPI\routes\videosid.js:23:5
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

this is also the same code that I was using before it crashes it was working perfectly fine I did not change anything.

EDIT: I've made some changes and I got this error message instead :

```
'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.'
```

Comment: you should quickly change your API key now that everyone has seen it

Comment: and from the error message, I guess you could try `router.get(... async (req, res, next) => { ...` for a start ? (adding the **next** method)

Comment: @gui3 actually adding the next method the way you told me too works but now it just seems that the problem comes from me exceeding my daily quota, and thanks for remiding about my api key i got around to change it.